# Zip Multiple files with multiple result in Python

Tags: python

Good Day!.

I would like to ask how can you convert a list of ".xlsx(excel)" file from specific folder location to ".zip" files.
Example:
Path:= C:\My_Program\zip_files

Inside my zip_file folder i have multiple ".xlsx" files.
Test1.xlsx
Test2.xlsx
Test3.xlsx

and i want the output to be in same folder but zip individually.
Output:
Test1.zip
Test2.zip
Test3.zip

Hope somebady can help me i am new to python2 or python3.

Comment: You should list any actions you have attempted so far, stack overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: show your code and error message.

Comment: import zipfile
import os

working_folder = 'C:\\My_Program\\zip_files\\'

files = os.listdir(working_folder)

files_py = []

Comment: for f in files:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(str(f) + '.zip', 'w') as myzip:
        if f.endswith('.xlsx'):
            ff = os.path.join(working_folder, f)
            files_py.append(ff)
            for f1 in files:
                myzip.write(f1)

for a in files_py:
    ZipFile.write(os.path.basename(a), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

Comment: put code in question. There will be more readable.

Answer (score 3):

You have standard module `zipfile` to create ZIP, and `glob.glob()` or `os.listdir()` or `os.walk()` to get filenames in folder.

---

**EDIT:** should works (I works for me on Linux)

```
import os
import zipfile

folder = 'C:\\My_Program\\zip_files'

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):

        name_without_extension = filename[:-5] # string `.xlsx` has 5 chars

        xlsx_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        zip_path =  os.path.join(folder, name_without_extension + '.zip')

        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w')

        # use `filename` (without folder name) as name inside archive
        # and it will not create folders inside archive
        zip_file.write(xlsx_path, filename)

        zip_file.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** the same with `glob`

```
import os
import glob
import zipfile

folder = 'C:\\My_Program\\zip_files'

for file_path in glob.glob(folder+'\\*.xlsx'):

    filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
    print(filename)

    name_without_extension = filename[:-5]
    print(name_without_extension)

    xlsx_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    zip_path =  os.path.join(folder, name_without_extension + '.zip')

    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w')

    # use `filename` (without folder name) as name inside archive
    # and it will not create folders inside archive
    zip_file.write(xlsx_path, filename)

    zip_file.close()
```